# Convert SHA1 Hex to Base 16 Integer

Tags: go, hex

I need some help porting an algorithm from Ruby to Go.

In Ruby I have:

```
hex = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(str).to_i(16)
hex.to_s(32)
```

Which creates a SHA1 hex string, converts it to an integer in base 16 and then back to a string in base 32.

How do I achieve the same in Go?

Comment: Are we talking about base 32 representation of the result or [Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) encoding? Would be nice if you'd posted some example input and output.

Comment: Fore quick testing purpose, running the ruby code with str = "example" outputs "od4po9p9ec57v03uve37da9dpdnokfsf"

Comment: With steps : str = "example" gives hexdigest => "c3499c2729730a7f807efb8676a92dcb6f8a3f8f", to_i => 1114894757552854782121625437503858766054806929295, to_s => "od4po9p9ec57v03uve37da9dpdnokfsf"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example code (playground : https://play.golang.org/p/izBIq97-0S):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/base32"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    // Input
    exampleString := "example"

    // SHA1 hash
    hash := sha1.New()
    hash.Write([]byte(exampleString))
    hashBytes := hash.Sum(nil)

    // Conversion to base32
    base32str := strings.ToLower(base32.HexEncoding.EncodeToString(hashBytes))

    fmt.Println(base32str)
}
```

I tested it agaisnt this Ruby script and the ouput matches :

```
require 'digest'

str = "example"
hex = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(str).to_i(16)

puts hex.to_s(32)
```

---

Edit : here is my original answer, which reproduces every step from the ruby script, but two of them are unnecessary (playground : https://play.golang.org/p/tyQt3ftb1j) :

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/base32"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    // Input
    exampleString := "example"

    // SHA1 hash
    hash := sha1.New()
    hash.Write([]byte(exampleString))
    hashBytes := hash.Sum(nil)

    // Hexadecimal conversion
    hexSha1 := hex.EncodeToString(hashBytes)

    // Integer base16 conversion
    intBase16, success := new(big.Int).SetString(hexSha1, 16)
    if !success {
        panic("Failed parsing big Int from hex")
    }

    // Conversion to base32
    base32str := strings.ToLower(base32.HexEncoding.EncodeToString(intBase16.Bytes()))

    fmt.Println(base32str)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I Was looking for

Comment: @ZoharArad: I just edited my code with a shorter version : the hexadecimal (string and big Int) steps were completely unecessary

Answer (score 3):

try this

```golang
h := sha1.New()
h.Write(content)
sha := h.Sum(nil)  // "sha" is uint8 type, encoded in base16

shaStr := hex.EncodeToString(sha)  // String representation

fmt.Printf("%x\n", sha)
fmt.Println(shaStr)
```

Example Output...

```sh
fcbc340d999e751840e17f862cc9eaf826cc6079
fcbc340d999e751840e17f862cc9eaf826cc6079
```